# Can't execute Android emulator: Permission denied

Tags: android, android-emulator

I can't execute my Android emulator from Eclipse. Therefore now I'm trying to do it using command line. My OS is Ubuntu. I've got the following message:

```
bda@bda-EasyNote-TJ75:~$ ~/android-sdk-linux/tools/emulator -avd Android40 -wipe-data -no-boot-anim -cpu-delay 0
Could not launch '/home/bda/android-sdk-linux/tools/emulator-arm': Permission denied
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Permissions seem broken. Try

```
chmod +x /home/bda/android-sdk-linux/tools/emulator-arm
```

Answer (score 0):

what do u mean by can't execute emulator from eclipse may be u downloaded the corrupted version of android. plz confirm that it is corrupted version or not.see these 3 videos of the entire setting up process to make sure that you did not goof up somewhere!

1) http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=suDrc8Deznw\http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1dsxnLwy-m8

3) http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EEs_Szwq-Po